Keycloak SES with IAM Role based permission
Is it possible to use SES without username and password (by turning off the authentication) in Keycloak?
I asked why this error before here. But now i am doubting even SES without authentication is possible in keycloak?
More info from other post:
I added policy for the user the IAM user for send email via SES.
But, whenever I am trying to configure it without Authentication i am getting two errors with different ports,
2024-08-29 14:08:56,827 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource] (executor-thread-340) Failed to send email
org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, 25; timeout 10000;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

and
org.keycloak.email.EmailException: org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Authentication required

My keycloak configuration is as follows,


Thanks in advance for your help :)
